# С++ программа не компилируется

Tags: c++, visual-c++

*Первое знакомство с языком выдалось не очень удачным.
Задача программы заключается в:

1. Получить на вход 2 массива.
2. Найти пересечения этих массивов, занести их в третий массив.
3. Естесна, вывести всё на экран.

Во время запуска Visual начал ругаться на 40й строке. Больше запустить её не удаётся.*

```
 #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        int i, j;
        int n1, n2;
        int pmax = 0;
        cin >> n1 >> n2;
    
        int *ms1 = new int[n1];
        int* ms2 = new int[n2];
   
    
        int* cms = new int[n1 + n2];
    
        for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            cin >> ms1[i];
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
            cin >> ms2[i];
        }
    
    
        for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            j = 0;
    
            while (j != n2) {
                if (ms1[i] == ms2[j]) {
                    cms[pmax] = ms1[i]; //Вот тут появилась ошибка.
                    pmax++;
                } else{
                        j++;
                }
            }
            
        }
    
    
        for (i = 0; i < pmax; i++) {
            cout << cms[i] << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: `} else{` в цикле `while` лишний - зацикливается на первом `ms1[i] == ms2[j]`

Comment: `Больше запустить её не удаётся.` думаю что поможет меню `отладка -> стоп` или что то в этом роде

Comment: > Visual начал ругаться на 40й строке. - Visual Studio или Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else 
{
 j++
}
```

Лишнее!Оставь просто `j++`